Weird image URL for dynamic import of images
I have a json file with image names
{
    "img": "placeholder.jpg",
    "title": "124 ave NW",
    "sqft": "1319",
    "bedrooms": "3",
    "bathrooms": "3"
  },

im trying to dynamically import these images based on the img name
<template>
  <div class="project">
    <img width="350px" height="300px" :src="getImgUrl(img)" class="project-image" />
    <h1 class="project-title">{{ title }}</h1>
    <div class="project-details">
      <div class="bedroom-container"><img :src="bedIcon" /> {{ bedrooms + ' bedroom' }}</div>
      <div class="bathroom-container"><img :src="bathIcon" /> {{ bathrooms + ' bathroom' }}</div>
      <div class="size-container">{{ sqft + ' Sq. Ft.' }}</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

using a function getImgUrl to properly resolve that image import
const getImgUrl = (img: string) => {
  return new URL(`./assets/images/${img}`, import.meta.url).href
}

looking at this code to me i understand this as take the image name which is placeholder.jpg and append the proper url to it. This should come back as src/assets/images/placeholder.jpg
However when i take a look in dev tools i see the following url resolved for the img component
http://localhost:5173/src/components/project-display-component/undefined
Im very lost and confused about this, how is it possible its getting the completely wrong URL
I have looked around at the vite guide for static assets: https://vitejs.dev/guide/assets.html
as well as added the base: './src' to my vite.config.ts under defineConfig
Am i missing some sort of vite config step?

If the images are in /src/assets/images, we wouldn't expect to find them in a subfolder below the current module. Instead of import.meta.url, start from the project root as the base...
const getImgUrl = (img: string) => {
  return new URL(`/src/assets/images/${img}`, window.location.origin).href;
}


This works thank you. I'm a bit confused on this. How did you come to this conclusion. Is there anything I can read up on. Ive only ever dealt with this in a company level and using import.metal.url was the suggestion so seeing window.location.origin sticks out to me

Glad it was helpful. I guess your reading assignment should be the docs for the URL class constructor. I can see how you might get into a groove, if you've handled a lot of working code that bases paths from the current module; you might start to become blind to that base path param. But import.meta.url says "start walking the source tree from this module". That's an awkward trip when the asset path is invariant and in a totally different part of the three than the code.
